# Postional Binding and ParameterSets

Tags: powershell, parameter-sets

I'm struggling to understand the behavior of parameter sets and positional binding. Here is the sample function.

```
function Test-PositionBinding {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'ParamSet2')]
    param (
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ParamSet1',Position = 0)]
        [int]
        $param1,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ParamSet1',Position = 1)]
        [int]
        $param2,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ParamSet2',Position = 0)]
        [int]
        $param3
    )    
    process {
        $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName
        $param1
        $param2
        $param3
    }
}
```

Based on the help output it would seem that calling the function with a single int should use paramset1 and calling it with 2 int should use paramset2 which is what i would expect.

```
SYNTAX
    Test-PositionBinding [[-param3] <int>] [<CommonParameters>]

    Test-PositionBinding [[-param1] <int>] [[-param2] <int>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

However, I receive the following output.

```
PS C:\> Test-PositionBinding 1
ParamSet2
0
0
1
PS C:\> Test-PositionBinding 1 2

Test-PositionBinding: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '2'.
```

I would have expected the following.

```
PS C:\> Test-PositionBinding 1 2
ParamSet1
1
2
0
```

If we change the type of param1 to a string the function works as expected.

```
PS C:\> Test-PositionBinding 1
ParamSet2

0
1
PS C:\> Test-PositionBinding 'abc'
ParamSet1
abc
0
0
PS C:\> Test-PositionBinding 'abc' 2
ParamSet1
abc
2
0
```

What is it that I am misunderstanding about the way PS interprets parameter sets?

Ultimately my question, is why is PS unable to differentiate between 2 parameter sets with positional binding and different parameter counts if the first parameter is of the same type between sets.

Answer (score 1):

> [As per the MS Docs:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameter_sets?view=powershell-7)
>
> Parameter set requirements The following requirements apply to all
>   parameter sets.
>
> Each parameter set must have at least one unique parameter. If
>   possible, make this parameter a mandatory parameter.
>
> A parameter set that contains multiple positional parameters must
>   define unique positions for each parameter. No two positional
>   parameters can specify the same position.
>
> Only one parameter in a set can declare the ValueFromPipeline keyword
>   with a value of true. Multiple parameters can define the
>   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName keyword with a value of true.
>
> If no parameter set is specified for a parameter, the parameter
>   belongs to all parameter sets.

This is a good write up on this topic that kept around that helped me. Snipping it here, vs just giving you the link to bounce over to. Thogh this is not parameterset specific, the same rules apply.

> [Specifying PowerShell Parameter Position](https://powershellstation.com/2017/10/04/specifying-powershell-parameter-position)
>
> It makes sense for some commands to allow you to pass things by
>   position rather than by name, especially in cases where there would be
>   little confusion if the names of the parameters are left out (as in
>   this example).

```
function Test-Position
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [parameter(Position=0)]$parm1,
        [parameter(Position=1)]$parm2,
        [parameter(Position=2)]$parm3,
        [parameter(Position=3)]$parm4
    )
}
```

> What should I do?
>
> ***> According to the help (about_Functions_CmdletBindingAttribute), you
>   should use the PositionalBinding optional argument to the
>   CmdletBinding() attribute, and set it to $false.***
>
> That will cause all parameters to default to not be allowed by position. Then, > you can specify the Position for any (hopefully only one or two) parameters
>   you wish to be used by position.
>
> For instance, this will only allow $parm1 to be used by position:

```
function Test-Position
{
    [CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding = $false)]
    Param([parameter(Position=0)]$parm1,
                                    $parm2,
                                    $parm3,
                                    $parm4)
}
```

> But wait, it gets easier
>
> Even though the help says that all parameters are positional by
>   default, it turns out that using Position on one parameter means that
>   you have to use it on any parameters you want to be accessed by
>   position.
>
> For instance, in this version of the function I haven’t specified
>   ositionalBinding=$False in the CmdletBinding attribute, but only the
>   first parameter is available by position.

```
function Test-Position2
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [parameter(Position=0)]$parm1, 
                                $parm2, 
                                $parm3, 
                                $parm4
    )
}
```

> That’s interesting to me, as it seems to contradict what’s in the
>   help. Specifically, the help says that all parameters are positional. 
>   It then says that in order to disable this default, you should use the
>   PositionalBinding parameter.  This shows that you don’t need to do
>   that, unless you don’t want any positional parameters.
>
> As a final example, just to make sure we understand how the Position
>   value is  used, consider the following function and syntax help:

```
function Test-Position3
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        $parm1,
        $parm2,
        [parameter(Position=1)]$parm3,
        [parameter(Position=0)]$parm4
    )
}
```

> By including Position on 2 of the parameters, we’ve ensured that the
>   other two parameters are only available by name. Also, the assigned
>   positions differ from the order that the parameters are defined in the
>   function, and that is reflected in the syntax help.

Answer (score 0):

If you add an IF you can see when you choose param 1 or 2 you are in paramset 1

if you choose param1 or 2 you can't select param 3 or 4

if you run Test-postionbinding 1

Then since param1 is defined as 0 it will powershell will automatically bind the first parameter passed to the function to position 0.
if you pass 0 -param4 1
Param3 will have a value of 0 and param4 will be 1 and you fall into paramset2.

If you specify param1 then your only other parameter is param2 because its a member of Paramset1

If you choose param3 then the only other available param is param4 because it's part of paramset2

```
function Test-PositionBinding {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'ParamSet2')]
    param (
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ParamSet1',Position = 0)]
        [int]
        $param1,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ParamSet1',Position = 1)]
        [int]
        $param2,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ParamSet2',Position = 0)]
        [int]
        $param3
    )    
    process {
        if($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "paramset1")
        {
            write-output "Paramset1"
            $param1
            $param2
        }

        if($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "paramset2")
        {
            write-output "Paramset2"
            $param3
            $param4
        }
    }
}
```

Observing position 2 binding

```
Test-PositionBinding -param1 1 10
Paramset1
1
10
```

Observing paramset2

```
Test-PositionBinding -param3 10
Paramset2
10
```

using no parameter names and forcing powershell to use the binding specified:
Test-PositionBinding 0 1
Test-PositionBinding : A position

```
al parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '1'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Test-PositionBinding 0 1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Test-PositionBinding], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Test-PositionBinding


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Test-PositionBinding 0
Paramset2
0
```

Comment: I just updated to clarify. If we change the type of the first position parameter in either set to a different type it then works as expected.This is what i fail to grasp.

Comment: your default param set is paramset2 . I think what's happening when you specify more than what is in the default.. in your case you have 2 items in paramset1 and one param in param set2 so if you don't specify a param it takes the default and default has only one param so if you pass two params to default. it'll error since it doesn't know where to bind the second argument too.

Comment: it would appear positional binding only seems to work with the default . change your default in the beginning of the Function and see if you get the behavior you want

Comment: If i change the default parameterset to ParamSet1 then there is no way to invoke the postional parameter for ParamSet2 as PS uses ParamSet1 and assumes a 0 for the missing positional param